# "Illegal storage address" with tex4ebook, tex4ht error

Tags: errors, tex4ebook

I got the following error message while running tex4ebook

```
--- warning --- File `EBGaramond-Regular-lf-ts1.htf' starts/ends with character code 255 (instead of 246)
--- warning --- File `EBGaramond-Regular-lf-ts1.htf' starts/ends with character code 255 (instead of 246)
--- error --- Illegal storage address
```

And gives an error Code 1, without an epub file output.

Do I need to reproduce the error in a MWE? Or is there a solution for it without?

**Update 1**

In the named htf file the first 9 line are as follows:

```
EBGaramond-Regular-lf-ts1 11 255
'&#x00B8;' '' cedilla 11
'&#x02DB;' '' ogonek 12
'&#x201A;' '' quotesinglbase 13
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'' ''
'&#x201E;' '' quotedblbase 18
```

Does anybody know what that mean?  Is there a bug somewhere?
By the way, looking with notepad++ at the encoding of this file, it is utf8 (without BOM).

**Update 2**

I try to make a MWE, but this seems to be hard. The following are the last line of the compling error running tex4ebook. Maybe it helps? I try to reproduce the error in a MWE and will come back.

```
Searching `EBGaramond-Regular-lf-t1.htf' for `EBGaramond-Regular-osf-t1.htf'
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/EB_Garamond_Regular/EBGaramond-Regular-lf-t1.htf)
[1
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 1
C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 1:
```

**Update 3 - The Minimal Working example**

I found a MWE that represents what is going on while running tex4ebook and getting the above error of illegal storage address:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{nextpage}
\usepackage{bbding}
% needs bbding.4ht by Michal H. in same folder for tex4ebook run
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
% needs pagenote.4ht by Michal H. in same folder for tex4ebook run
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{%
    \ifpnhaschapter%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{chapter}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{chapter}}%
    \fi%
    \else%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{section}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{section}}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
    \addtonotes{\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\protect\noindent\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}\textsc{\large #1}}%
}% by Michal H.
\newcommand{\Quoteforchapter}[3]{%
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{minipage}{#3}\small
            \noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\emph{#1}}\\[0.35\baselineskip]
            \raggedleft\scriptsize #2
        \end{minipage}
\end{flushright}}

\begin{document}
When running \TeX4ebook the following will happen:
 
\Quoteforchapter{>>Just to comment this out separately\\
    the error disappears<<}{Some author}{0.4\textwidth}

\addtonotesnewcommand{First Chapter: Just to comment this out the error disappears}

\textsc{A Name}: Just to comment this out separately the error disappears\footnote{A footnote that becomes an pagenote}

\AsteriskThinCenterOpen : Just to comment this out separately the error disappears

\printnotes

\end{document}
```

When I say "the error disappears" I mean that an epub file is generated. With the error no file is generated (error Code 1).

**Update 4 - Moving the file to a fresh directory**

I moved the `.tex` and the two `.4ht` files (bbding, pagenote) to a fresh directory, first under `OneDrive/...` and then under `C:/...`. But in both cases the error remains. I used not my `.cfg` and not my `.mk4`. The error looks as it was before:

```
...
Transcript written on Testdocument_illegalstorageaddress.log.
[INFO]    mkutils:  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html
[INFO]    mkutils: executing: tex4ht  -cmozhtf -utf8 -cmozhtf -utf8 "Testdocument_illegalstorageaddress.dvi"
--- error --- Illegal storage address
....
Searching `EBGaramond-Regular-lf-t1.htf' for `EBGaramond-Regular-osf-t1.htf'
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/EB_Garamond_Regular/EBGaramond-Regular-lf-t1.htf)
[1
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command tex4ht returned exit code 1
C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 1:
```

I further do not have any idea what could now be done.

I tried in addition another font, I used `\usepackage{lmodern}`. With this the error disappear, in both under OneDrive and Windows C:/.

How to fix this for the used fonts `ebgaramond`?

Comment: Your chances of a solution will go up markedly if you add an MWE.

Comment: I know, but my source.tex is huge. If I approximately knew where possibly the error can be found, I could easier manage the MWE. I already had an idea, but the error could not be reproduced. So isnt there a small hint where I can look at it?

Comment: Is there any possibility that one or more of your files, not necessarily the fonts, begin with a byte order mark (BOM) ? For example, the little-endian utf-16 BOM begins with hex FF, which is code 255.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I had to read what BOM byte order mark is, and found, that my sourcename.tex is in utf8 converted (without BOM), just last week with notepad++. Before it was ansinew encoded. So, this might not help.

Comment: A MWE might help, but: (a) What is your operating system? (b) Are you root, user, Android? (c) Are you using any kind of script (outside of TeX itself) for processing? If so, examine the script for BOM. (d) Which year TeXlive or MiKTeX?  (e) Have you mingled files from different operating systems?

Comment: Did you check the htf files mentioned in the message?

Comment: Thank you rallg and Ulrike Fischer, I will look in details for it later. But for now: (a) Window 11, (b) root mean administrator account on win? (c) I dont think that I use any kind of script, not consciously, (d) TeXlive 2023, just installed 2 days ago, (e) yes, sometimes I transfer from android smartphone txt file via OneDrive, integrate them via copypaste in my tex files and work on win11 with these adds on my projects. - @Ulrike, I need to  check the htf files later this day. Thank you two, I will come back and report.

Comment: See Update 1 above in the question. Might this be a bug?

Comment: I believe the htf code, from update 1, is simply a correspondence between HTML Entities and the corresponding Adobe Glyph Name. I am not familiar with the syntax, but my wild guess is that it is OK. And now for some brute force: What happens if you change the 255, in the top line of the posted htl code, to 246?

Comment: The `htf` warning probably doesn't have anything in commong with the `illegal storage address error. Without proper MWE it is impossible to tell what happens here, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for caring. See Update 2, maybe it helps. I try hard to find a MWE to reproduce the error. I will come back.

Comment: From The Sound of Music, song Do-Re-Mi: "Let's start at the very beginning, a very good place to start." So I ask, what happens if you do not use that font? Try a MWE that simply uses TeX default fonts (Such as Latin Modern Roman). If you do not use Garamond Math but MiKTeX still complains, what happens if you remove that font from the system?

Comment: See Update 3, with Minimal Working Example. I am curious to know how to solve this error. @rallg I really need this font I can not change to another.

Comment: Due to not having all packages (and not yet TL2023) I cannot test your MWE. As for the font: Consider downloading that font from CTAN directly (not via MiKTeX or command line), or use a different source if available. Over-write the existing font files with the new download (you could do `texmf-local` but in this case over-write might be better). Also, math fonts often have an accompanying *sty and possibly *def file; over-write that too.

Comment: @rallg When I run tex4ebook on another tex file with the same fonts as here, I got the same `Warnings` concerning the font (255/246). But without an error, and get an output epub file. So it seems, as Michal H. said, this might nothing has to do with the fonts. The MWE here in Update 3 will be the best what needs to be recognized.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, but I also don't get the HTF warnings with your MWE.

Comment: Thank you Michal. We not yet talked about the `.cfg` file. Which one are you using?

Comment: When I run `tex4ebook -a debug Testdocument.tex` the error remains. So the problem does not has to do with the `.cfg` file. Should I install texlive 2023 anew? What else could be the problem?

Comment: @Thomkrates no, TeX Live should be fine. Try to move the file to a  fresh directory, without any temporary files. I found an older report that this helped.

Comment: I tried this, and added Update 4 to the question.

Comment: To come to a summary: If the MWE works under your (@michal.h21) TeXLive 2023 and you do not get any error message; and it does **not** work under my TeXLive 2023, and the error vanishes with another font (lmodern) under my system... it might be necessary to install TeX Live 2023 anew. Doesnt it?

Comment: @Thomkrates no, fresh reinstall of TeX Live wouldn't help. Maybe it is some issue caused by Windows, as the `Illegal storage address` error was always reported by Windows users and I couldn't reproduce it (this is not the first time). Anyway, if other fonts help, then you can use them conditionally. With TeX4ht, used fonts are usually not that important anyway.

Comment: Ok., for this `.tex` file I will use another suitable font to generate the epub file. With the other `.tex` files of my projects this seems not to be a problem up to now. Strange. Thank you, Michal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `illegal storage address` disappeared `when using the above MWE`. But it is unclear why exactly, since in other sourcename.tex file the error is still there.

I was runing `tex4ebook -a debug -c config.cfg -e build.mk4 Testdocument.tex "fonts"` with the option `"fonts"` using the earlier `ebgaramond` font, like in the MWE, and the output resulted in an epub file. Where the day before the above error occured without epub output running tex4ebook without this option `"fonts"`.

But when I now again run tex4ebook `without` the option `"fonts"` also no error occures, which should, since the day before it resulted in the above error.

Maybe someone else knows a further suitable answer to the whole question and answer here?