# Again: Error: "Illegal storage address" with tex4ebook

Tags: fonts, tex4ebook

In spring I got the same error and here we found that changing to another font would solve the problem. (See ["Illegal storage address" with tex4ebook, tex4ht error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680793/illegal-storage-address-with-tex4ebook-tex4ht-error)) But now with three other fonts (ebgaramond, lmodern, stix2) the same error appears with the `tex4ht error code 1`.

I also used today the tlmgr update tex4ht to get the newest version of it.

Is in the meanwhile some knowledge arosen for another solution that could help and not just change the font?

Thank you.

Comment: you didn't learn much from your older question didn't you? You have an unknown document that you compile in an unknown way in an unknown OS and unknown TeXsystem and hope that someone can guess why it errors. Sorry but my crystalball  is not up to the task. Give enough data so that someone can try to reproduce your error.

Comment: I learned from last time, that there is no solution to it, also not with MWE. But within the last hour I tried two other fonts (bookman and the default: European Computer Modern) and `get an valid epub` without errors. It seems to be a font problem that no one could or would like to be solving. In spring we had extensional discussions about that as you can see in the reference, Ulrike Fischer. Michal H. said that with ebooks the fonts are not that important and changing to another is easier than to look for the problems with some specific fonts. Look at his last comment in above reference.

Answer (score 0):

I got an valid epub just by changing to another font for compiling with tex4ebook. I tried `bookman` and the `default (European Computer Modern)` without loading a special font. Just like it is said in the latex font catalogue. With this no error in epubcheck occurs and gives an valid epub.